# SASS look up like in stylus

Tags: sass, stylus, bem

It is even possible with parent ampersand - `&`?

Something like this

```
.block
    &--mod
        {???}__elem
            color: red
```

To this

```
.block--mod .block__elem {
    color: red; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't something like [Partial Reference](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#partial-reference) in SASS but you can do this:

```
.block
  $root:&
  @at-root
    #{$root}--mod
      #{$root}__elem
        color: red
```

It's not as clean as you can archieve in Stylus but works.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your CSS in the following way:

```
.block
    &--mod &__elem
        color: red
```

I don't think it is possible using the structure you provided.

Comment: I am a newbie in sass. Sometimes the structure can be much deeper.  In the case of stylus I would use `& ^[0]__elem`. Anyway, thanks for idea.